# Простая нейросеть выдает результат ~0.5

Tags: javascript, нейронные-сети

Пытаюсь реализовать простую нейронную сеть прямого распространения. Но результат, который она выдает после обучения(методом обратного распространения ошибки) стремиться к значению 0.5. Хоть после 1000 эпох обучения, хоть после 10000. Она имеет 3 входа, 2 нейрона в скрытом слое и 1 нейрон результирующий.

А если не обучать её, а с только что сгенерированными весами заставить принимать решение, то её ответ колебается в диапазоне от 0.5 к 1.

Вот код того, что есть на данный момент.

```js
/*var weight_1 = [[0.79, 0.44, 0.43],
                [0.85, 0.43, 0.29]],
    weight_2 = [[0.5, 0.52]],*/
var weight_1 = randArr(2, 3),
    weight_2 = randArr(1, 2),
    learning_rate = 0.05,
    data = [
        [[0,0,0], 0],
        [[0,0,1], 1],
        [[0,1,0], 1],
        [[0,1,1], 0],
        [[1,0,0], 1],
        [[1,0,1], 0],
        [[1,1,0], 0],
        [[1,1,1], 1]
    ];
console.log("---------До тренировки---------");
console.groupCollapsed("Prediction before");
predictSet(data);
console.groupEnd();
function randArr(rows, cols) {
    arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j<cols; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = Math.random();
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

function activation(x) {
    return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x));
}

function sumMultVector(A, B) {
    var C = 0;
    for (var i=0;i<A.length;i++) {
        C += A[i] * B[i];
    }
    return C;
}

function getWeightLayer(inputs, weight) {
    var getWeightLayer = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<weight.length; i++) {
        getWeightLayer[i] = activation(sumMultVector(inputs,weight[i]));
    }
    return getWeightLayer;
}

function predict(inputs) {
    outputs_1 =  getWeightLayer(inputs, weight_1);
    outputs_2 = getWeightLayer(outputs_1, weight_2);
    return outputs_2[0];
}

function train(inputs, expected) {
    weights =  getWeightLayer(inputs, weight_1);
    weights_2 = getWeightLayer(weights, weight_2);
    
    predict_2 = weights_2[0];
    error_2 = predict_2 - expected;
    sigmoid_2 = predict_2 * (1 - predict_2);
    delta_2 = error_2 * sigmoid_2;
    
    weight_2[0][0] -= weights_2[0] * delta_2 * learning_rate;
    weight_2[0][1] -= weights_2[0] * delta_2 * learning_rate;
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            error_1 =  weight_2[0][j] * delta_2;
            sigmoid_1 = weights[j] * (1 - weights[j]);
            delta_2 = error_1 * sigmoid_1;
            weight_1[j][i] -= inputs[i] * delta_2 * learning_rate;
        }
}

function compareRandom() {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
}

function trainSet(data) {
    for (var k = 0; k < 5000; k++) {
        data.sort(compareRandom);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            train(data[i][0], data[i][1])
        }
    }
}
function predictSet(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log("спрогнозировало:", predict(data[i][0]), "ожидается:",data[i][1]);
    }
}
trainSet(data);
console.log("---------После тренировки---------");
console.groupCollapsed("Prediction after");
predictSet(data);
console.groupEnd();
console.groupCollapsed("Weights");
console.log("От входного слоя к скрытому: ", weight_1);
console.log("От скрытого к выходному: ", weight_2);
console.groupEnd();
```

И моя проблема заключается в том, что все результаты, которые выдает этот алгоритм, близки к 0.5 и довольно случайны, независимо от того, какие аргументы я использую.

Было бы неплохо если у кого-нибудь найдется похожая, но рабочая нейронная сеть. Тогда я мог бы получить результат тренировки на определенных статичных весах и ориентироваться на правильности своей нейросети.

Comment: А распределение весов проверяли? И пробовали использовать другой алгоритм генерации начальных?

Comment: @yar85 Пробовал задавать вручную веса, результат тот же. Вот пример распределения весов. Допусти изначально они выглядят так:
От входного слоя к скрытому
[[0.34154, 0.48588, 0.36448]
[0.47394, 0.79290, 0.52845]]
От скрытого к выходному
[0.54270, 0.03027]
После 1000 итераций тренировки они преобразились в
[[0.70796, 0.29439, 0.47045]
[0.03797, 0.97974, 0.47748]]
и
[-0.3225, 0.31591]
соответственно

Comment: На чем обучаете? Может ваша сеть в принципе не может обучиться на тех данных.

Comment: @sanmai, она имеет 3 входа, 3 нейрона в скрытом слое и один выходной. Обучаю на подобных входных данных [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0] и т.д. В качестве результата, которые ожидаются от каждого из входных данных ставлю значение на свое усмотрение

Comment: Это нужно вам в вопрос добавить. Идеально бы чтобы был скрипт, который любой мог бы запустить чтобы посмотреть на работу вашей программы.

Comment: Как выглядит график ошибки?

Comment: Категорическая есть какая-то проблема в алгоритме. Даже на самом простом наборе данных сеть не учится ничему. Нужно смотреть какие размеры матриц получаются у вас на каждом из слоев. Может позже внимательней посмотрю.

Comment: @sanmai, размеры матриц получаются правильные. Я изучал значения переменных на каждом шаге, на вид все правильно

Comment: Откуда черпаете вдохновение, если не секрет?

Comment: Просто мало нейронов, нужно не 3, а 5 или больше в скрытом слое.

Comment: Что значит простая? Разве такое бывает? Это же мозг, который может развиваться.

Comment: @And неронные сети к мозгу имеют очень отдалённое отношение, развиваться они сами пока ещё не могут

Comment: @sanmai, С этого видео https://youtu.be/HA-F6cZPvrg
Начиная с 19 минуты он начинает делать реализацию сети 3-2-1 на python. У него она почему-то работает очень идеально. Даже лучше чем ваш пример на synaptic)

Comment: @RealPeha тогда вам бы какой клон numpy использовать чтобы умножение матрица руками не делать https://github.com/nicolaspanel/numjs

Comment: Если вам хочется действительно с низов изучить вообще всю тему машинного обучения и нейронных сетей, то вам сюда: https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning - детали тут может быть не совсем актуальны, но всякая математика вся та же самая что сейчас, что раньше (говорю про начало 2018 года)

Comment: @sanmai, клон numpy это то, что нужно, я пытался найти что-то похожее, спасибо! Я не хочу использовать готовые библиотеки, т.к. планирую написать диплом про нейронные сети. Тема мне очень интересна и я хочу в деталях показать, как там все работает. Но застрял даже на самом простом...

Comment: Не использовать математические библиотеки - это странно. Вы же диплом не про умножение матриц пишите, правда?

Comment: @sanmai, нет, математическая библиотека мне как раз пригодится. Я говорю про готовые реализации нейронный сетей, такие как synaptic или brain.js. Они мне ни к чему, поэтому и пытаюсь написать с нуля

Comment: @RealPeha ни в коем случае не рекомендую этого; numpy и аналоги это именно математические библиотеки, а не библиотеки готовых нейронных сетей

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Возьмём фреймворк для постройки сетей, воссоздадим архитектуру вашей сети и... Увидим что даже заведомо правильная работающая сеть не может выявить закономерности в ваших входных данных. Для заведомо отрицательного образца `[1,1,0]` сеть показывает результат в пределах 0.5. Если посмотреть на ошибку обучения, то на 20000 итерациях она будет порядка 0.2, из чего самого по себе можно сделать вывод что архитектуры сети недостаточно.

Вы можете сколько угодно пытаться исправить алгоритм, но у вас ничего не получится без изменения и усложнения архитектуры. В качестве эксперимента можно попробовать руками подобрать веса, которые бы давали правильный ответ. Уверен что это невозможно сделать даже человеку, что уж говорить об алгоритмах, [которые даже с горы толком спуститься не могут](https://fosterelli.co/executing-gradient-descent-on-the-earth).

```js
var myNetwork = new synaptic.Architect.Perceptron(3, 2, 1)

var trainer = new synaptic.Trainer(myNetwork)

var trainingSet = [
  {
    input: [0,0,0],
    output: [0]
  }, {
    input: [0,0,1],
    output: [1]
  }, {
    input: [0,1,0],
    output: [1]
  }, {
    input: [0,1,1],
    output: [0]
  }, {
    input: [1,0,0],
    output: [1]
  }, {
    input: [1,0,1],
    output: [0]
  }, {
    input: [1,1,0],
    output: [0]
  }, {
    input: [1,1,1],
    output: [1]
  }
]

var trainingOptions = {
  rate: .1,
  iterations: 20000,
  error: .005,
}

console.log(trainer.train(trainingSet, trainingOptions));

console.log(myNetwork.activate([0,0,1]));
console.log(myNetwork.activate([1,0,0]));
console.log(myNetwork.activate([1,1,1]));
console.log(myNetwork.activate([1,1,0]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/synaptic/1.1.4/synaptic.min.js"></script>
```

Если усложнить структуру, добавив три нейрона в скрытом слое... То система для того же отрицательного образца `[1,1,0]` показывает результат близкий к 0.1, то есть - ожидаемо негативный. Ошибка обучения минимальная. Это, конечно, не обязательно хорошо, но для нашего минимального 
 и исчерпывающего набора данных к ошибке нет вопросов.

(Хватило бы добавить и двух нейронов, но для надёжности - лучше больше.)

```js
var myNetwork = new synaptic.Architect.Perceptron(3, 5, 1)

var trainer = new synaptic.Trainer(myNetwork)

var trainingSet = [
  {
    input: [0,0,0],
    output: [0]
  }, {
    input: [0,0,1],
    output: [1]
  }, {
    input: [0,1,0],
    output: [1]
  }, {
    input: [0,1,1],
    output: [0]
  }, {
    input: [1,0,0],
    output: [1]
  }, {
    input: [1,0,1],
    output: [0]
  }, {
    input: [1,1,0],
    output: [0]
  }, {
    input: [1,1,1],
    output: [1]
  }
]

var trainingOptions = {
  rate: .1,
  iterations: 20000,
  error: .005,
}

console.log(trainer.train(trainingSet, trainingOptions));

console.log(myNetwork.activate([0,0,1]));
console.log(myNetwork.activate([1,0,0]));
console.log(myNetwork.activate([1,1,1]));
console.log(myNetwork.activate([1,1,0]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/synaptic/1.1.4/synaptic.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Добавил в скрытый слой еще 3 нейрона. Результат все еще сходится к 0.5. 
https://jsfiddle.net/v8z4pmfd/2/

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос надо задавать. Вам надо начать с самого простого. Например, сделайте сеть для расчёта XOR. Эту сеть можно даже на бумажке посчитать вручную, так что вы будете видеть что лажает ваш алгоритм или правильно считает.

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря пользователю sanmai я наконец решил свою проблему! Больше недели стараний, и вот у меня уже готовая нейронная сеть. Полностью переписал функцию тренировки, оказалось я использовал неправильные формулы.
Привожу код, может кому-нибудь пригодится

```js
var hiddenLayer = 4,
    weight_1 = randArr(hiddenLayer, 2), //(скрытий слой, входной слой)
    weight_2 = randArr(1, hiddenLayer), //(выходной слой, скрытый слой)
    learning_rate = 1,
    data = [
            [[0,0], 1],
            [[0,1], 0],
            [[1,0], 0],
            [[1,1], 1]
        ];
function randArr(rows, cols) {
    arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j<cols; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = Math.random() - 0.5;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

function activation(x) {
    return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x));
}

function multVector(A, B) {
    var C = 0;
    for (var i=0;i<A.length;i++) {
        C += A[i] * B[i];
    }
    return C;
}

function getWeightLayer(inputs, weight) {
    var getWeightLayer = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<weight.length; i++) {
        getWeightLayer[i] = activation(multVector(inputs,weight[i]));
    }
    return getWeightLayer;
}

function predict(inputs) {
    outputs_1 =  getWeightLayer(inputs, weight_1);
    outputs_2 = getWeightLayer(outputs_1, weight_2);
    return outputs_2[0];
}

//Обратное распространение ошибки
function train(inputs, expected) {
    outputs_1 =  getWeightLayer(inputs, weight_1);
    outputs_2 = getWeightLayer(outputs_1, weight_2);
    
    //Дельта выходного нейрона
    predict_2 = outputs_2[0];
    delta_2 = predict_2 * (1 - predict_2) * (expected - predict_2);
    
    //От выходного слоя к скрытому
    delta_1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < hiddenLayer; i++) {
        delta_1[i] = outputs_1[i] * (1 - outputs_1[i]) * weight_2[0][i] * delta_2;
        grad = outputs_1[i] * delta_2;
        //Меняем вес
        weight_2[0][i] += grad * learning_rate;
    }
    
    //От скрытого к входному
    for (var j = 0; j < hiddenLayer; j++)
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            //Вычисляем смещение
            grad = inputs[i] * delta_1[j];
            //Меняем вес
            weight_1[j][i] += grad * learning_rate;
        }
}

function compareRandom() {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
}

//Тренировка сети
function trainSet(data) {
    for (var k = 0; k < 5000; k++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            train(data[i][0], data[i][1])
        }
    }
}

//Вывод результата
function predictSet(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log("p:", predict(data[i][0]), "e:", data[i][1]);
    }
}

trainSet(data);
predictSet(data);
```

Осталось привести код в порядок и расширить архитектуру для решения задач посложнее. И еще она вроде как с локального минимума не выходит. Читал, что для этого применяется еще один параметр - момент, который так же как и скорость обучения определяется методом подбора, но мне не удалось это реализовать. Надеюсь это не скажется плохо в дальнейшем